# SELECT results from another table AS column array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I can't figure out how to get results from 2 tables, in 1 query result (can't simple JOIN)

I have these 2 tables in my MySQL database:

```
Table 1: sales
id
name
info

Table 2: users
sale_id
user_id
```

Now, every sale have different number of assigned users. Some sale have 2 users, some sale have 10 users.

In single row, I need to have columns from `sale` table, and all assigned users to it (connected with same Sale_id)

I need result, something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cfgb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some insight on your programming language would have been nice.
And yes, as suggested by wogsland and icoder, one typically use joins and loop through results to build en array. But the use of GROUP_CONCAT, as Yoleth pointed out, is what you need. I don’t know if it was the goal here, but it can reduce memory used in the result because there is no row repetition.

```
SELECT info FROM Sales AS s,
(
    SELECT sale_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS assigned_users
    FROM Users 
    GROUP BY sale_id) AS u 
WHERE s.id=u.sale_id;
```

In a single query, with a fancy JOIN:

```
SELECT s.info AS info, u.sale_id AS sale_id, GROUP_CONCAT(u.user_id) AS assigned_users 
FROM Sales AS s LEFT JOIN Users AS u 
ON s.id=u.sale_id 
WHERE sale_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY u.sale_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The goal is to get all assigned User ID's in sub-objects, and then join some other columns for every user. I know to to make it in 2 queries, or 1 query and some php adjustments, but I was curious, is MySQL able to do something like this in single query.

Comment: You can use a JOIN if you really need it, but it's less readable and I doubt the keys would be used as effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT s.*,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.user_id SEPARATOR ', ')
         FROM users u 
        WHERE u.sale_id = s.id) AS users
 FROM sales s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join two tables and get query result set like this:

```
saleID | saleName | userID | userName
1      | Oct Sale | 5      | Tim   
1      | Oct Sale | 6      | Nik
2      | Nov Sale | 7      | Bill
```

Then you can walk each row and build associative array from that data:

```
$sales = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['saleID'], $sales)) {
        $sales[$row['saleID']] = array(
           'saleID'   => $row['saleID'], 
           'saleName' => $row['saleName'],
           'users'    => array()
        );
    }
    array_push($sales[$row['saleID']]['users'], array(
        'userID' => $row['userID'],
        'userName' => $row['userName']
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, MySQL isn't going to return you a nice nested array like that. But you can create it by looping through the result. Assuming your MySQL connection is named `$mysqli` then try something like

```
$sales = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT sales.*, users.user_id FROM sales, users WHERE sales.id = users.sales_id");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sales[$row->id]['sales_id'] = $row->id;
    $sales[$row->id]['name'] = $row->name;
    $sales[$row->id]['info'] = $row->info;
    $sales[$row->id]['assigned_users'][] = $row->user_id;
}
```